# how to get a value created in a test function for next test function when testing using pytest in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, pytest

Sorry if this is a basic concept in pytest but I'm a beginner in pytest and I have yet to find an answer for this. I have a python file that has several functions (code_to_be_tested.py). Output of each function is needed by the next function to work. I want to use pytest to test these functions (test_code.py). I want to use each test function in test_code.py to test 1 function in code_to_be_tested.py but I cannot figure out a way to provide output of each function inside a test function to next test function.

I'll try to explain what I mean by below code examples,

```
# code_to_be_tested.py

def func1(nm=""):
    file_name = "".join(["file", nm, ".txt"])
    open(file_name, "w")
    return file_name

def func2(filename):
    path = "/home/"
    return "".join([path, filename])

x = func1()
y = func2(x)
```

```
# test_code.py

from code_to_be_tested import func1, func2
import pytest

def test_func1():
    try:
        e = func1("one")
        assert isinstance(e, str) is True
    except AssertionError as asErr:
        raise asErr

def test_func2():
    try:
        f = func2()
        assert isinstance(f, str) is True
    except AssertionError as asErr:
        raise asErr
```

I understand that I can use fixture as shown below but it creates duplicate files and outputs.

```
# test_code.py

from code_to_be_tested import func1, func2
import pytest

def test_func1():
    try:
        e = func1("one")
        assert isinstance(e, str) is True
    except AssertionError as asErr:
        raise asErr

@pytest.fixture
def fix1():
    out = func1()
    return out

def test_func2(fix1):
    try:
        f = func2(fix1)
        assert isinstance(f, str) is True
    except AssertionError as asErr:
        raise asErr
```

I'd like to be able to return "e" local variable from test_func1() and "f" from test_func2() and use them in other test functions. Please let me know if there's anyway I can achieve this.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622565/pytest-pass-value-from-one-test-function-to-another-in-test-file

Comment: I feel like wanting to use output from individual tests as inputs to "higher-level" tests may be unhelpful. A test failure ideally points to a single problem; if `e` and `f` flow into test `g`, and `g` fails, a dev has to wonder if the generators of any `e`, `f`, or `g` are to blame. Test them all individually, even if that means making their dependencies explicit such that you can inject everything `g` needs.

Comment: @Pantelis this is not a duplicate. the solution shared there is incorrect and irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Lancetarn you are right. However in the actual code, I'm testing e and f thoroughly and making sure there are no exceptions. So, when there's an error in g, I'll be sure to check g, not the previous tests.